# iPhone: Store and Display Push Notification

Tags: iphone, apple-push-notifications

In my iphone application, I want to store all the push notifications that a device receives and then display it in table.

I also want to show the number of notifications received till now on application icon.

Is this possible?

Can anyone please help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can not store push notification. Your app is closed and the notification are received by the os, if the user press ok button the os will open your application.

What you can do is to keep all the notification on your server and when the app is open sync your local data with the server data.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Will think over this suggestion. But what about displaying the number of notifications on the icon? Is this possible?

Comment: The number is set by the os on your app icon, and must be in the push, after the app is open you can set it programmatically     [UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber = 7;

Comment: @ Terente Ionut Alexandru Sorry, but i didn't understand your last comment. Can u pls spare some time to explain it? I want to get the badge updated without opening the application.

Comment: You must send the badge number in the last push.

Comment: Look at the following, application:handleActionWithIdentifier:forRemoteNotification:completionHandler: